# homebrew failing to install closure-compiler

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, homebrew

It seem that my system is failing to install closure-compiler. This is whats happening with computer:

```
$ brew install closure-compiler   
==> Checking out http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/    
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.8.6.dylib    
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/svn    
  Reason: image not found    
Error: Failure while executing: svn checkout -q --force http://closure-compiler.googlecode.com/svn/trunk    / /Library/Caches/Homebrew/closure-compiler--svn -r 2388
```

Comment: May the additional seo crumb trails help lead another wayward developer here quicker: In my case, installing platform.sh cli on mac mountain lion failed at composer global install require with:

    [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException] 
    The process has been signaled with signal "5". 

Following @AndyLi's answer below resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced a similar problem after upgrading the homebrew installed svn.

I solved it by `brew rm svn serf neon` and then `brew install svn` as suggested in https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/17172

Remember to reopen your terminal after that.

Comment: That's exactly what I did to solve this, I just forgot to close it! Thanks!!